# Does Radium not work with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, radium

I want to change the color of the Tab component for smaller devices. Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import React from 'react'
import Radium from 'radium'

const inkBarStyle = {
    background: 'green',
    '@media screen and (max-width: 399px)': {
        background: 'red'
    }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Tabs inkBarStyle={inkBarStyle}>
                <Tab label="Tab 1" />
                <Tab label="Tab 2" />
                <Tab label="Tab 3" />
            </Tabs>
        )
    }
}

export default Radium(MyComponent)
```

Radium is correctly imported into my project - it's being used on `<div>` elements and such. It doesn't work with Material UI though. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: I've been having a heck of a time, too. I opened an issue with a MVC example here: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/964 ... hopefully we'll get a working example out of it.